# OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted - Python

Tags: ruby, process, operating-system, multiprocessing, signals

I have an automation tool that starts a Ruby on Rails server using the command line:

```
from subprocess import Popen
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'r+')
self.webserver = Popen(server_cmd, shell=True, stdin=devnull, stdout=devnull,
                       stderr=devnull, close_fds=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

The webserver is a process that contains the server running as a separate process (the way it is supposed to be). So I have the `stop_webserver` method to kill the process and stop the Rails server:

```
def stop_webserver(self):
    """
    Stop the Rails server, if there is one running or it was created.
    Kill the process and all of its children, in order to avoid having a
    zoombie processes.
    """
    if self.webserver is None:
        self.log.info("Server isn't running. Nothing to do.")
        return

    if self.is_server_running():
        # os.killpg(self.webserver.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
        self.log.info("PID: %s" % self.webserver.pid)
        # self.log.info("PID: %s" % os.getpgid(self.webserver.pid))
        time.sleep(10)
        os.killpg(self.webserver.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
        self.webserver = None
        self.log.info("Server was stopped.")
```

However I'm always getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unit/front_end_test.py", line 27, in runTest
    frontend.stop_webserver()
  File "front_end.py", line 184, in stop_webserver
    os.killpg(self.webserver.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

If I try to terminate the process using `os.getpgid` I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unit/front_end_test.py", line 27, in runTest
    frontend.stop_webserver()
  File "front_end.py", line 182, in stop_webserver
    self.log.info("PID: %s" % os.getpgid(self.webserver.pid))
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

However, the server is still running at port 3001. The process was never killed. How can I properly terminate the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by forcing a `os.system()` kill:

```
def stop_webserver(self):
    """
    Stop the Rails server, if there is one running or it was created.
    Kill the process and all of its children, in order to avoid having a
    zoombie processes.
    """
    if self.webserver is None:
        self.log.info("Server isn't running. Nothing to do.")
        return

    if self.is_server_running():
        try:
            # os.killpg(self.webserver.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
            os.killpg(self.webserver.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            self.webserver = None
            self.log.info("Server was stopped.")
        except OSError, e:
            self.log.exception(e)
            self.log.info("PID: %s" % self.webserver.pid)
            os.system("sudo kill %s" % (self.webserver.pid, ))
```